# md5sum of ubuntu 12.04 i386 desktop .iso does not match

Tags: iso

I downloaded the 12.04i386desktop.iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. the startup disk creator when creating the bootable usb says that checksum does not match.

I repeated the download many times using torrents too, with no avail.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check md5 hash of your downloaded image with the [official posted hashes page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

   A how to guide is available [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)
2. If the hashes matched and the problem persists, install  [7zip](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/p7zip-full) [image: Install 7zip].
3. Download unetbootin from [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), make it executable. Launch it and create your disks. **Do this only if the hashe matches**

Comment: So what would one do if the hash does not match?

Comment: Need to redownload. But that page isn't updated for 12.04.1 (which is current version). Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/180230/35775)

Comment: Can you put this in the post so future users can see this?

Answer (score 0):

Check md5 hash of your downloaded image with the [official posted hashes page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes), and [use e.g. zsync](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/ZsyncCdImage) to fix corrupt *.iso images.