# Where can I get the hash for 12.04.1 ISO?

Tags: 12.04, md5sum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find the md5sums of Ubuntu ISO images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9417/where-to-find-the-md5sums-of-ubuntu-iso-images)

Where can I get the hash for 12.04.1 ISO? 
Is it the same for 12.04?
I can't find it.

Comment: Each image has a different hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *not* the same; a hash is individually calculated for each ISO image.

Visit the [Release Directory page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/) , here as

[image]

Comment: Thanks! There isn't at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: I hope they will update it

Comment: The page is 'Immutable'. Not everyone can update it, of course :)

Comment: Yes at the bottom they mentioned that ,, To request an update to this list, please open a bug on the [ubuntu-docs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bugs) package in Launchpad.